# How to keep texture size whatever the size of the object?

Tags: texturing, materials

First post here.
I want to create characters made of different meshes. Those objects will have different material (color, specular…) but I want them to have the same texture, like a plastic grain. So I added a grain bump to each of my materials.
But Blender scales up and down the texture size depending on the size of the objects.

My wish is that all objects have the same scale.
Is there a way to create my matrial for each object without any texture, and then add a second material to all my objects at once, like a Photoshop grain overlay ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried a *Mapping* node before the *Image Texture* node and adjusting the *Scale* for the different objects?

Comment: Have you applied scale to all of your objects (Ctrl+A > Scale)? Also, try using "Object" Texture Coordinates instead of "Generated" (default).

Comment: Thanks @Blunder & Christopher Bennett, but I'm new to this forum AND also to Blender ! 
Here are my shading nodes, where do I have to put Image texture or Texture coordinate nodes ? (I'm not used to that nodes stuff…)
[CLICK HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/s875uw7sy4t5ii6/Nodes.jpg?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to give each object the same texel density. This defines how much area of the image is mapped onto the 3D object.

A *Checker Texture* can give you a good visual impression of this. Make sure that for all your objects the *Scale* is applied to them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, *Scale* in *Object* mode).

UV maps help to minimize distortion and stretching. It gives you the most control. In the *UV Editor* workspace you can unwrap your objects.

To change the scale of the textures, add *Mapping* and a *Texture Coordinate* node in the *Shader Editor*. Connect the *UV* output (or try *Generated* or *Object*) of the *Texture Coordinate* node to the *Mapping* node. Then adjust the *Scale* values in the *Mapping* node. I've used 1.3 for the torus, 2.3 for the sphere, and 1.0 for the cube. But the values depend on the UV map layout and the model.

Alternatively, you can scale the UV islands (<kbd>S</kbd>) in the *UV Editor* (top left in the screenshot).

**The goal is to have all squares of the checker texture almost the same size** with a minimized amount of distortion and stretching. Then the grain textures will have the same scale, too.

[image: screenshot texture mapping]

For the bumps I've used a *Texture Image* node with an image. You can use here the *Voronoi* node as you did. When you're happy with the scale of the grain texture just remove the *Checker Texture* nodes.